# Почему анимация дёргается и встаёт в исходное положение вместо того, чтобы продолжаться?

Tags: html, css, css3

```css
.header_mid {
  height: 100px;
}
.header_mid .logo_slide {
  padding: 25px 0;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.header_mid .logo_slide ul {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}
.header_mid .logo_slide .logo_item {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  float: left;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
.header_mid .logo_slide ul:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_mid">
  <div class="logo_slide">
    <ul>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://www.webmoney.ru/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/1" alt="WebMoney logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://perfectmoney.is/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/2" alt="PerfectMoney logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://qiwi.com/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/3" alt="Qiwi logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://money.yandex.ru/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/4" alt="YandexMoney logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://www.okpay.com/ru/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/5" alt="OkPay logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://advcash.com/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/6" alt="ADVcash logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://www.paypal.com/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/7" alt="PayPal logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://payeer.com/ru/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/8" alt="Payeer logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://bitcoin.org/ru/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/9" alt="Bitcoin logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://www.onecoin.eu/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/10" alt="OneCoin logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://www.swiscoin.com/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/11" alt="SwisCoin logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

У меня есть бегущая строка с логотипами, но к моменту завершения первого цикла и начала второго, анимация дёргается и встаёт в исходное положение. Не понимаю, как решить эту проблему.

Бегущая строка должна быть сделана без использования js и должна быть резиновой.
Javascript крайний вариант.

[Вот ссылка на мою бегущую строку](http://jsfiddle.net/tfsc3qkp/).

Comment: что значит сбрасывается?

Comment: @EatMyDust посмотри до конца анимации и поймёшь. Мне нужно чтобы анимация продолжалось, и без пустой области.

Comment: https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/photobanner/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прошло много времени с момента публикации вопроса, а я так и не написал решение. Решения оказалось костлявым. Исходя из комментариев пользователя @Утка было решено дублировать список и подогнать параметры анимации так, чтобы новый запуск анимации происходил ровно в тот момент, когда выезжает дубль. Все это с фиксированной шириной списка.

```css
.header_mid {
  height: 100px;
}

.header_mid .logo_slide {
 padding: 25px 0;
 height: 50px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
  width:100%;
  margin: auto;
}
.loop, .loop-clone {
  display: block;
  -width: 200%;
  width:1510px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.loop {
  animation: marquee 60s linear infinite;
}
.loop-clone {
  animation: marquee-clone 60s linear infinite;
}

.header_mid .logo_slide .logo_item {
 height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  float: left;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0% { left: 0; }
  50% { left: -1510px; }
  50.001% { left: 1510px; }
  100% { left: 0; }
}
@keyframes marquee-clone {
  0% { left: 1510px; }
  50% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -1510px; }
}

.header_mid .logo_slide:hover ul,.header_mid .logo_slide .loop-clone ul {
 animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_mid">
      <div class="logo_slide">
          <ul class="loop">
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://perfectmoney.is/"><img src="/images/logos/perfect-money.png" alt="PerfectMoney logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://qiwi.com/"><img src="/images/logos/qiwi.png" alt="Qiwi logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://money.yandex.ru/"><img src="/images/logos/yandex.png" alt="YandexMoney logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://www.okpay.com/ru/"><img src="/images/logos/okpay.png" alt="OkPay logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://advcash.com/"><img src="/images/logos/advcash.png" alt="ADVcash logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://www.paypal.com/"><img src="/images/logos/paypal.png" alt="PayPal logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://payeer.com/ru/"><img src="/images/logos/payeer.png" alt="Payeer logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://bitcoin.org/ru/"><img src="/images/logos/bitcoin.png" alt="Bitcoin logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://www.onecoin.eu/"><img src="/images/logos/onecoin.png" alt="OneCoin logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://www.swiscoin.com/"><img src="/images/logos/swiscoin.png" alt="SwisCoin logo" /></a>
          </ul>
          <ul class="loop-clone">
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://perfectmoney.is/"><img src="/images/logos/perfect-money.png" alt="PerfectMoney logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://qiwi.com/"><img src="/images/logos/qiwi.png" alt="Qiwi logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://money.yandex.ru/"><img src="/images/logos/yandex.png" alt="YandexMoney logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://www.okpay.com/ru/"><img src="/images/logos/okpay.png" alt="OkPay logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://advcash.com/"><img src="/images/logos/advcash.png" alt="ADVcash logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://www.paypal.com/"><img src="/images/logos/paypal.png" alt="PayPal logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://payeer.com/ru/"><img src="/images/logos/payeer.png" alt="Payeer logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://bitcoin.org/ru/"><img src="/images/logos/bitcoin.png" alt="Bitcoin logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://www.onecoin.eu/"><img src="/images/logos/onecoin.png" alt="OneCoin logo" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://www.swiscoin.com/"><img src="/images/logos/swiscoin.png" alt="SwisCoin logo" /></a>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Проблема в установке ширины.

В примере 7-ой элемент идет под первым, поэтому он визуально перекидывает на 1-ый элемент. Если расширить блок, то он дальше будет крутить.

Уверен, что задавать ширину в % таким способом есть плохо.

```css
.header_mid {
  height: 100px;
}
.header_mid .logo_slide {
 padding: 25px 0;
 height: 50px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.header_mid .logo_slide ul {
  display: block;
  width: 350%;
  height: 50px;

  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;

  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}
.header_mid .logo_slide .logo_item {
 height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  float: left;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -250%; }
}

.header_mid .logo_slide ul:hover {
 animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
   <div class="header_mid">
      <div class="logo_slide" >
          <ul>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://www.webmoney.ru/"><img src="/images/logos/wm.png" alt="WebMoney logo1" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://perfectmoney.is/"><img src="/images/logos/perfect-money.png" alt="PerfectMoney logo2" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://qiwi.com/"><img src="/images/logos/qiwi.png" alt="Qiwi logo3" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://money.yandex.ru/"><img src="/images/logos/yandex.png" alt="YandexMoney logo4" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://www.okpay.com/ru/"><img src="/images/logos/okpay.png" alt="OkPay logo5" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://advcash.com/"><img src="/images/logos/advcash.png" alt="ADVcash logo6" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://www.paypal.com/"><img src="/images/logos/paypal.png" alt="PayPal logo7" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://payeer.com/ru/"><img src="/images/logos/payeer.png" alt="Payeer logo8" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://bitcoin.org/ru/"><img src="/images/logos/bitcoin.png" alt="Bitcoin logo9" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://www.onecoin.eu/"><img src="/images/logos/onecoin.png" alt="OneCoin logo10" /></a>
            <li class="logo_item"><a href="https://www.swiscoin.com/"><img src="/images/logos/swiscoin.png" alt="SwisCoin logo11" /></a>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tfsc3qkp/6/

Comment: Я так и не понял чего хочет автор, это же не красиво, когда при завершении она дёргается и встаёт в исходное положение

Comment: @Doofy Мне нужно чтобы анимация продолжалось.

Comment: Есть идея по решению с циклом. Дублируем список и подгоняем параметры анимации так, чтобы новый запуск анимации происходил ровно в тот момент, когда выезжает дубль. Тот еще костыль правда кмк

Comment: @Утка, костыль ужасный

Comment: @Doofy, ну если Вы знаете решение без js лучше, я с радостью посмотрю

Comment: @Утка, ничего не знаю

Answer (score 2):

```css
.header_mid {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo_item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo_slide {
  display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: scroll 4s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```

```html
<div class="header_mid">
  <div class="logo_slide">
    <ul>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://www.webmoney.ru/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/1" alt="WebMoney logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://perfectmoney.is/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/2" alt="PerfectMoney logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://qiwi.com/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/3" alt="Qiwi logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://money.yandex.ru/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/4" alt="YandexMoney logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://www.okpay.com/ru/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/5" alt="OkPay logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://advcash.com/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/6" alt="ADVcash logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://www.paypal.com/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/7" alt="PayPal logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://payeer.com/ru/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/8" alt="Payeer logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://bitcoin.org/ru/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/9" alt="Bitcoin logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://www.onecoin.eu/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/10" alt="OneCoin logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="logo_item">
        <a href="https://www.swiscoin.com/">
          <img src="https://satyr.io/150x50/11" alt="SwisCoin logo" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если правильно понял вопрос то так. Не совсем понятно что нужно, чтобы анимация завершалась до конца и резко восстанавливалась или нужно повторение

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы анимация продолжалось, и без пустой области. И у тебя какой-то разгон в начале

Comment: да, нужно чтобы цикл продолжался бесконечно и без пустой области между первым и вторым и тд циклом

Comment: @Doofy, ну какой "разгон из-за подгрузки внешних ресурсов"? Вы сами-то разобрались что написали?( Пустая область это из-за того, что анимация заново запускается.

Comment: Есть идея как это пофиксить "без js", описал комментом в посте выше.

Comment: @Утка, не знаю как зарепитить элементы, это не изображение